# If statements with true or false in python 3.7.1 Tanner Short

Tags: python-3.x

my name is Tanner Short.
I'm a beginning developer, and have recently started to use python. 
For a simple project I wanted to create a basic calculator, but I wanted to be creative and add some if statements and such. Here is my code.

```
name = input("Please enter your name: ")
age = input("Please enter your age: ")
Yes = True
No = False

print("Hello " + name + "!" " You are "+age+ " years old!" )

welcome_question = input("Would you like to go to the calculator? ")

if Yes:
print("Moving on..")
else:
print("Thank you for your time!")
```

So when I ran the file, it was supposed to ask for your name, age, then ask if you'd like to go to the calculator.
But the if statement isn't working. When I type Yes, it works, then when I type No, it outputs what was supposed to happen if you said yes.

Sorry if this made no sense! I a beginner and just need a little help. Thank you.

Comment: Your indenting is broken, and `Yes` is always True...

Comment: I recommend to use f-strings for your outputs. It makes your code easier to read and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the wrong values. What you want to do is, you want to compare user's input with Yes. If the user enters `Yes` then `if` should work, otherwise `else` should work.

So, basically, you need to compare welcome_question with "Yes" or "No". The Line 3 and 4 from your code are not required as per. And yes, your indentation is also broken.

```
name = input("Please enter your name: ")
age = input("Please enter your age: ")

print("Hello " + name + "!" " You are "+age+ " years old!" )

welcome_question = input("Would you like to go to the calculator? ")

if welcome_question == "Yes":
   print("Moving on..")
else:
   print("Thank you for your time!")
```

I hope it works. Cheers!